# Simplifying $\sum _{t=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(1+g\right)^{ \lceil t/2\rceil}}{\left(1+k\right)^t}$

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

how to simplify this expression so that I get an expression only?

when $t = 1, 2,.... $

$$y = \sum _{t=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(1+g\right)^{ \lceil t/2\rceil}}{\left(1+k\right)^t}$$

I know that for t = 1,  $\lceil \frac{t}{2}\rceil$ = 1

for t = 2,  $\lceil \frac{2}{2}\rceil$ = 1

for t = 3,  $\lceil \frac{3}{2}\rceil$ = 2

for t = 4,  $\lceil \frac{4}{2}\rceil$ = 2

so in general $\lceil \frac{t}{2}\rceil = \frac{t}{2}$ if t is even, and $\lceil \frac{t}{2}\rceil = \frac{t+1}{2}$, if $t$ ia odd. And I can split this expression into two parts the even part and the odd part. The problem I am facing is I dont know how that affect the summation symbol, should I let $t = 2k$, and substitute $t = 2k$ for the even part and sub that into the summation and the t at the denominator?

EDIT: (continuing from @mag's suggestion)

$\sum _{t=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(1+g\right)^{ \lceil \frac{t}{2}\rceil}}{\left(1+k\right)^t}$

$=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(1+g\right)^{\lceil n\rceil}}{\left(1+k\right)^{2n}}+\frac{\left(1+g\right)^{ \lceil\frac{2n-1}{2}\rceil}}{\left(1+k\right)^{2n-1}}$

$=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(1+g\right)^{n}}{\left(1+k\right)^{2n}} + \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(\frac{\left(1+g\right)^{ n}}{\left(1+k\right)^{2n}} \times \frac{1}{\left(1+k\right)^{-1}})$

$= (1 + \frac{1}{\left(1+k\right)^{-1}}) \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(1+g\right)^{n}}{\left(1+k\right)^{2n}} $

using the geometric sum to infinity formula:
$$ \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\: ar^{k-1} = \frac{a}{1-r}$$

and given that

$(\frac{1+g}{(1+k)^2})^{-1}\times(\frac{1+g}{(1+k)^2}) = 1$

$= (1 + \frac{1}{\left(1+k\right)^{-1}}) \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(1+g\right)^{n}}{\left(1+k\right)^{2n}} \times (\frac{1+g}{(1+k)^2})^{-1}\times(\frac{1+g}{(1+k)^2})$

$= (1 + \frac{1}{\left(1+k\right)^{-1}}) \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:(\frac{\left(1+g\right)}{\left(1+k\right)^{2}})^n \times (\frac{1+g}{(1+k)^2})^{-1}\times(\frac{1+g}{(1+k)^2})$

$= (\frac{1+g}{(1+k)^2})(1 + \frac{1}{\left(1+k\right)^{-1}}) \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\: 1 \times (\frac{1+g}{(1+k)^2})^{n-1}$

where $r = \frac{1+g}{(1+k)^2}$ and $a = 1$

and applying the formula:

$= (\frac{1+g}{(1+k)^2})(1 + \frac{1}{\left(1+k\right)^{-1}}) \times \frac{1}{1- (\frac{1+g}{(1+k)^2})}$

I can try to simplify even more but just wanted to make sure I am on the right track, especially in terms of applying the infinite geometric sum formula.

There is also another part of the question which is that what is the condition of g so that $y$ is finite. In this case, since $|r| < 1$

$r = \frac{1+g}{(1+k)^2} < 1$

$g < k(k+2)$

Comment: Not affection to your summation because what you make is just change some symbols by its equal.

Comment: You are on the right track and used the geometric sum formula correctly. And it seems like you are aware that the geometric sum formula for $a\neq 0$ only holds if $|r|<1$. Be aware that this condition says also that the series $y$ is absolute convergent, what made it easy for us to justifi all the steps in our calculation. And by your proof you also showed that $g<k^2+2k$ is a sufficient condition for $y$ to be finite.

Comment: If you want to proof $y$ to be finite if and only if ..., then I recommend you to take a look at the nth-term test.

Comment: @mag Thank  you for the comments. Just one more thing, since the working is alright, I guess the next steps could be simplifying the terms even more and what is the difference between absolute convergence and not absolute?

Comment: the difference between absolute convergence and not absolute (conditionally convergence) is that the first have a really "nice" behaviour when calculating, you can find plenty of information about it on google, like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence). Didn't check if all the steps were also possible without absolute convergence, but absolute convergence is definitly sufficent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you're describing is (almost) correct. Just be carefull as $k$ is already a variable in your calculation you have to substitute with a "free" variable like $t=2n$ for the even part and $t=2n-1$ for the odd part.
$$\sum _{t=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(1+g\right)^{ \lceil \frac{t}{2}\rceil}}{\left(1+k\right)^t}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(1+g\right)^{\lceil n\rceil}}{\left(1+k\right)^{2n}}+\frac{\left(1+g\right)^{ \lceil\frac{2n-1}{2}\rceil}}{\left(1+k\right)^{2n-1}}$$
By using $\lceil\frac{2n-1}{2}\rceil=n$ you have simplified the ceil symbol.

Comment: Hi mag, thanks for the help. Why does the RHS still have the ceil? I want to get rid of the ceil. Or it doesnt really matter

Comment: It's still there for better traceability. Getting rid of the ceil in the RHS is just a simple step by using $\lceil\frac{2n-1}{2}\rceil=n$ and $\lceil n \rceil=n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Thanks mag. I still have questions, if $\lceil \frac{t}{2}\rceil = \frac{t+1}{2}$ for the odd part, wouldnt that make $\lceil \frac{2n-1}{2}\rceil = \frac{2n-1+1}{2}$. Also another question, why $2n-1$ and why not $2n+1$?

Comment: And apparently two of them can simply into an infinite geometric sum? I am just tryng to simplify this expression to that.

Comment: I don't see your point, your thoughts are correct, but $\lceil \frac{2n-1}{2}\rceil = \frac{2n-1+1}{2}=n$ which exactly what I wrote...
$2n-1$ is the result of the substitution for the odd part. Of course you can transform it to have $2n+1$ by shifting the series, but it would require to shift the counting index everywhere.

Comment: And yes you can use the geometric series to simplify this more. You are on the right path to solve this task.

Comment: Hey mag thanks so much for your guidance. I have spent some time working on it and I would appreciate if you can give me some feedback on my new working. Please see the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the series as

$$
\sum_{r=0}^\infty\left({(1+g)^r\over(1+k)^{2r+1}}+{(1+g)^{r+1}\over(1+k)^{2r+2}}\right)
$$

Which is just taking two terms at once

Now you can split the sums into two infinite g.PS which you should be able solve easily

Comment: Unfortunately your way of rewriting the series is wrong.

Comment: @mag didn't quite get u could u explain a bit